# How does up/downvoting work exactly in terms of reputation and do some users have greater ability to affect ones reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, abuse, comment-voting

I'm really confused on voting.

Based on the link below I am assuming that comments do not affect reputation.

Can administrators or more "powerful" users for lack of a better term affect a user's reputation more than "regular" users?

Is there a way to see which user(s) is giving me upvotes and downvotes?

Is there a way to file a complaint if you think somebody is targeting you due to racism, bigotry, etc.? What is the mechanism for this?

I started in the SciFi and fantasy community, then joined Android and received an additional 100 points in both Android and SciFi. I did not receive an additional 100 points in SciFi when I joined META, although it states in the link below in the comments that I should for each time I join a community. Why didn't I receive an additional 100 points in SciFi again?

I edited my question based on the link below. If there are other links I should check out that'd be great.

Comment: That's a lot of questions. And they all have been asked before. You should start by definitely reading this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work

Comment: @Roombatron5000 thank you that was very helpful. I'll edit my question down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Based on the link below I am assuming that comments do not affect reputation.

Correct.

> Can administrators or more "powerful" users for lack of a better term affect a users reputation more than "regular" users?

No.

<sub>(Well, some employees can manually invalidate votes that have been determined to have been cast for the wrong reasons - for example, by fake accounts used to artificially inflate an account's reputation. But the reputation values attached to each type of vote are the same for all types of users.)</sub>

> Is there a way to see which user(s) is giving me upvotes and downvotes?

No, votes are anonymous by design.

> Is there a way to file a complaint if you think somebody is targeting you due to racism, bigotry, etc.? What is the mechanism for this?

Yes. We have scripts in place that monitor voting patterns and pick up on a lot of targeted voting. If you suspect this isn't enough, your first step is to flag one of your posts for moderator attention and get a moderator to take a look. Moderators *cannot* see individual votes, but they can see aggregated patterns and can often determine if someone is likely targeting you over time.

Beyond that, you can always reach us - the Stack Exchange team - by clicking "contact us" at the bottom of any page on the site.

> I started in the sci-fi and fantasy community, then joined Android and received an additional 100 points in both Android and Scifi. I did not receive an additional 100 points in Scifi when I joined META, although it states in the link below in the comments that I should for each time I join a community. Why didn't I receive an additional 100 points in scifi again?

You gain 100 reputation points *on the site you join*, not on every site you already have a profile on. The bonus is awarded once per site.

Comment: I see, thank you Anna. I appreciate your answer. What if the person you're concerned about could be a moderator? Is a moderator a person with a diamond by their name? And what is the difference between a moderator and the Stack Exchange team? How can I recognize this from your profile? Thanks again

Comment: @JMFB In that case, skip the flagging step and just contact us directly. Describe your concerns and we'll investigate. Yes, moderators are people with diamonds by their name. Unfortunately we don't have a good way to distinguish between diamonded employees and regular moderators, but an employee will always have something in their profile that mentions they work here. The employees you'll likely see most often are our community managers and you can find a full list of them [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do).

Comment: How do I send my concerns directly to the staff and bypass the moderators?

Comment: @JMFB Click "contact us" at the bottom of any page.

Comment: Thank you again. For some reason when other people edit my questions or answers I do not get the option to accept or not accept their edits. Some of the edits are incorrect grammatically and some have changed the meaning of the question to the point where it's not the same question. I'm kind of new here but I've been pretty active since I joined. I was just wondering how do I accept or reject an edit?

Comment: @JMFB Some edits are "suggested" - and you'll get a notification to review those (although other users may get to that before you) - but some apply right away if they're made by users with > 2000 reputation. You should be able to roll back if you disagree: click the "edited X ago" timestamp and you'll see a list of revisions. You should  see a "rollback" link on earlier ones. You can also just edit again to override any prior edits.